# Rails, Grape entity. Expose on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, grape-api, grape-entity

I have created grape entity:

```
class VehicleDetails < Grape::Entity
  expose :id
  expose :name
  expose :type
  expose :health, if: {type: 'basis'}
end
```

I want to expose `:health` if current `:type` is equal to `basis`. I try to access it by this method:

```
 get :details do
  present Basis.all, with: GameServer::Entities::VehicleDetails
 end
```

`Health` attribute does not shows in my created json. I thouht I could use `expose :health, if: :health`, it does not work too. What I am doing wrong???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are slightly misunderstanding what `:type` does within `Grape::Entity`. It does not refer to the class that is being exposed, but an option that you pass on the call to `present`. It is probably not suitable for your purpose, unless you always know the class of objects you are sending to `present` (I am guessing that may not always be the case and you have some polymorphism here).

I think you just want this:

```
class VehicleDetails < Grape::Entity
  expose :id
  expose :name
  expose :type
  expose :health
end
```

`Grape::Entity` will try a property and fail gracefully if it is not available or raises an error.

If other classes that you want to use do have the `health` property, but you want to hide those values, you can use the block form of `expose`:

```
class VehicleDetails < Grape::Entity
  expose :id
  expose :name
  expose :type
  expose( :health ) do |vehicle,opts| 
    vehicle.is_a?( Basis ) ? vehicle.health : nil
  end
end
```

Or you can pass a Ruby `Proc` as the condition:

```
class VehicleDetails < Grape::Entity
  expose :id
  expose :name
  expose :type
  expose :health, :if => Proc.new {|vehicle| vehicle.is_a?( Basis )}
end
```

This last one may be better if you don't want to show existing `health` property at all for classes which have it other than `Basis`